# Plotting a new figure showing the change in density (kg/m^3) with time in months

Tags: matlab

I'm attempting to derive potential density, sigma-1, from the (T,S,p) time series and plot a new figure showing the change in density (kg/m^3) with time in months.  I've managed to derive the potential density and have set up the change in density plot in the t5 tile just fine, but instead of plotting the change in density the t5 plot come out blank.  I need some advice on what I'm doing wrong with the t5 plot.

```
% plot mooring E time-series at 1000 m
load microcat.mat
load nortek.mat
% temp temperature deg C
% pres pressure dbar
% sal salinity PSS
% u eastward velocity m/s
% v northward velocity m/s
% date
```

```
figure()
ax=tiledlayout(4,1)
% tile temperature
t1=nexttile
plot(seabird.date,seabird.temp,'k')
ylabel('temperature (^{o}C)')
datetick('x','m')
grid on
ylim([0,10])
xlim([datetime(2016,04,01) datetime(2018,07,01)])
set(t1,'fontsize',10)
% tile salinity
t2=nexttile
plot(seabird.date,seabird.sal,'r')
ylabel('salinity (PSS-78)')
datetick('x','m')
grid on
xlim([datetime(2016,04,01) datetime(2018,07,01)])
set(t2,'fontsize',10)
% tile pressure(s)
t3=nexttile
plot(seabird.date,seabird.pres,'k')
hold on
plot(currentmeter.date,currentmeter.pres,'b')
axis ij
ylabel('pressure (dbar)')
datetick('x','m')
grid on
legend('microcat','nortek','location','southeast')
xlim([datetime(2016,04,01) datetime(2018,07,01)])
set(t3,'fontsize',10)
% tile potential density
pot_rho_t_exact = gsw_pot_rho_t_exact(seabird.sal,seabird.temp,seabird.pres,0)
t5=nexttile
plot(seabird.date,pot_rho_t_exact,'k')
ylabel('potential density (kg/m^3)')
datetick('x','m')
grid on
ylim([0,10])
xlim([datetime(2016,04,01) datetime(2018,07,01)])
set(t5,'fontsize',10)
%
title(ax,'mooring E at 1000m time-series','fontsize',18)
%set(gcf,'Position',[1000          87        1125        1250])
```

Comment: You jump straight from `t3` to `t5` - what happened to `t4`? Although you call them `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, etc., these are just naming conventions and the `nexttile` function will just return the next tile. This means that, even though you have called it `t5`, it is in the fourth tile positioin.

Comment: I omitted t4 from the code for posting the question cause it was for plotting something else entirely.  And altering the tile position to the fourth position doesn't change the outcome of the plotting.  It's plot(seabird.date,pot_rho_t_exact,'k') that I think I did wrong but I'm not sure how to correct for it so it plots the calculated potential density

Comment: Okay, in that case, what does `gsw_pot_rho_t_exact` do, and does it yield the answer you're expecting when you step through?

Comment: gsw_pot_rho_t_exact derives my potential density from salinity, temperature, and pressure.  And it yields the answer I'm expecting when I step through.  I just need to get that derived potential density to plot with it's corresponding month of data collection